# Background color on individual view in ListView

Tags: android, listview, compound-drawables

I'm building an android GUI and currently i'm building an ListView. I've based the rest of the appearence of my GUI on the backgroundcolor of individual views. I tried to do the same with my layout in the ListView but the commands do nothing. I've concluded by tests and some research that it's the ListView which forces transparency.

Is this possible to override? Please help :)